# Validacion y comparacion de fechas en python

Tags: python

compañeros estoy intentado hacer un programa que valide la fecha ingresada y luego la compare y retorne un true o false segun la validacion
el problema creo que esta en el if y no se si la sintaxis es valida de antemano muchas gracias

```
from datetime import datetime
def is_valid_date(fecha1):
    fecha2 = datetime.date(2001, 9, 30)
    if fecha1>fecha2:
       return True
    else:
        return False




a = True
while a == True:
        fecha = input("Ingresa una fecha en el formato YYYY-MM-DD: ")
        datetime.strptime(fecha, '%Y-%m-%d')
        resultado= is_valid_date(fecha)
        print(resultado)
        print("Fecha inválida")
        resp = input("Desea continuar? si / no ") 
        if resp == "no": 
            a = False
```

---

> Ingresa una fecha en el formato YYYY-MM-DD: 2020-3-5
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\ejemplo2.py", line 17, in 
> resultado= is_valid_date(fecha)
> File "C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\ejemplo2.py", line 3, in is_valid_date
> fecha2 = datetime.date(2001, 9, 30)
> TypeError: descriptor 'date' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object

> Process returned 1 (0x1)        execution time : 4.917 s
> Presione una tecla para continuar . . .

Comment: ¿Qué síntoma presenta? ¿Qué te imprime el `print(resultado)`? Debería imprimir `True` para féchas válidas (posteriores al 30 de septiembre de 2001) o `False` para las no válidas (anteriores a esa fecha)

Comment: Faltó guardar la fecha convertida a Datetime debes hacer `fecha = datetime.strptime(fecha, '%Y-%m-%d')`